# Is there a way to bind to a UWP TreeView that may have a variable number of levels like a folder structure would?

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-c++, uwp

Basically I want to use TreeView to represent a folder structure. So there maybe be any number of subfolders to navigate into. Can this be done via databinding, or does such logic have to be done all in code? Thanks.

Comment: *Can this be done via databinding* **yes**

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can I maybe get a HINT of a clue for kicking this off? I can easily bind to a collection of items in XAML, but I don’t know what XAML markup is used to bind to a unknown number of sub folders

Comment: official UWP TreeView documentation should be a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [TreeView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tree-view#bind-to-a-hierarchical-data-source) control supports binding to a hierarchical data source. You could define a custom class for binding usage.

I made a code sample for you reference:

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView x:Name="treeview" ItemsSource="{x:Bind storageFolders,Mode=OneWay}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:FolderInfo">
                <TreeViewItem ItemsSource="{x:Bind subFolders}" Content="{x:Bind FolderName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
    <Button Content="folders" Click="Button_Click"></Button>
</Grid>
```

```
public class FolderInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    private string _FolderName;
    public string FolderName
    {
        get { return _FolderName; }
        set
        {
            if (_FolderName != value)
            {
                _FolderName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("FolderName");
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<FolderInfo> subFolders { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return FolderName;
    }
}
```

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{

    public ObservableCollection<FolderInfo> storageFolders { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    }

    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FolderPicker folderPicker = new FolderPicker();
        folderPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder;
        folderPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".txt");
        var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        var Folders = await GetFoldersAsync(folder);
        foreach (var f in Folders)
        {
            storageFolders.Add(f);
        }
    }

    private async Task<ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>> GetFoldersAsync(StorageFolder storageFolder)
    {
        var folders = await storageFolder.GetFoldersAsync();
        ObservableCollection<FolderInfo> folderInfos = new ObservableCollection<FolderInfo>();
        foreach (var f in folders)
        {
            folderInfos.Add(new FolderInfo() {FolderName=f.DisplayName,subFolders=await GetFoldersAsync(f) });
        }
        return folderInfos;
    }
}
```

Then, when you have new sub folders, you just need to add it to the `storageFolders` collection.

Comment: Love this answer! This make my day today.